# Where to get sdk drawable resources for Lollipop

Tags: android, sdk, resources, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

Every android version comes with some drawable files, as part of the sdk in

sdk>platforms>VERSION>data>res>drawable-SIZE

However, not all the ones in the v21 folder are Material. For example, I cannot find the new version of ic_menu_edit like that seen in the new GMail app released this week
Also, on the Android developers website, the Actionbar icon pack does not yet have the new ones
(https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html)

Where can i get them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the material design icons are available from the [official Github repository](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons).

Comment: thanks, where about would i find actionbar icons?

Comment: Action bar icons are `24dp` - you'll find them in all of the directories.

Comment: ah got them, theyve changed the file names slightly so my search didnt work. Thanks again

Comment: Make sure to accept the answer if this helped you.